# Grab Image Element From Element Background As A DOM Resource

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

Consider the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rf4hV/

In there I'm listening to a load for an `img`. When the image is loaded I get an `event` which has a `target` of an image resource.

1) Is there anyway to grab this resource when not using a jquery loader? How would I do that?

2) How could I grab the same resource for the `the-div` `background-image`? Essentially, I want to see the same properties as the `event.target` from question 1.

Comment: grab like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rf4hV/1/

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking for the image's properties and from `#the-div` rather than the `img`

Comment: which image's properties are you looking for? if you get the url of the background-image like I show in my answer, then you can extract all other properties from the image itself, would this not do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A jQuery way to get one element's bg image and add it to another DOM node:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf4hV/6/)

```
  $(function() {          
      var bgimg = $("#the-div").css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)/g,'');
      $("img").attr('src',bgimg);
      console.log($("img")[0]);
  });
```

this will give you the DOM image object with `src` attribute set to `#the-div`'s background.

**You could also do the same without jQuery, and even without adding the `img` element to the curent DOM tree**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf4hV/5/)

```
  var thediv = document.getElementById("the-div")
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(thediv, null).getPropertyValue('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)/g,'');
  console.log(img);
```

Now you have a DOM object and you can access its properties.

I hope this is what you wanted.
You can not access an background-image as a DOM object without constructing a DOM object from that background-image, but this is exactly what the above examples do.

Comment: Took me a sec to realize what you were doing. You know how you retrieved the `background-image` as a URL string? I'm trying to retrive the `background-image` as DOM Resource. The result should be the same as my original `console.log`.

Comment: I extended the answer to show how to get the image DOM object after you construct it form the bg image.

Comment: Ooh I think that's the one. Thanks Martin!

Comment: ok, I just answered to the comment you deleted, never mind =) Here I added another example that combines the approaches from my answer above: http://jsfiddle.net/rf4hV/7/

Comment: I noticed you're making a `new Image` which makes sense. Shouldn't the background image be an image resource somewhere already? That is the resource I'd really like to be able to grab, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I think the problem here is that styles get rendered separately form the DOM, or in other words, the `backgroundImage` of the computed style is set to `"url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png)"` this is what we can access with javascript, whereas the image itself is downloaded and rendered by the browser, and does not exist as a DOM entity and can not be accessed as such. So yes, I believe, to access an image's properties we need to initiate an image object in which we then load the image. You might find this useful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/